# Is it possible to connect a car air compressor to a blow out gun?

Tags: compressed-air, tools

I have a compressor with this type of outlet:

[image]

I am not sure how it is called, but it works for my bicycle and car.

Then I have a blow out gun to clean electronics by a stream of compressed air. The problem is that the blow out gun has a different inlet:

[image]

It makes an audible click when it connects.

I would like to connect the two, but unfortunately I cannot find any [adapter](https://www.amazon.de/s?k=kompressor%20adapter). The closest thing that remotely looks like it can do the job is this [coupling for a welding torch](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07WD53FWV/ref=sspa_dk_detail_3).

I have already used the two together with a plastic hose that I forcibly held in place by one hand while operating the blow out gun with the other. However, the lack of an adapter in the marketplace makes me wonder if I am doing something very wrong.

I see that there are essentially two types of compressors:

1. The ones that have this click-on outlet by default - generally more expensive
2. The ones that don't - generally cheaper

Is there a way I can make the compressor work with the blow out gun, or do I need to buy a second one?

Comment: Try searching for "schrader valve to quick connect adapters", maybe you can find something that works. I Googled that phrase and found things to buy, but I didn't check the specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your car has a tire infiltrator ; no. They are too low volume for any "blowing". Unless you want to build a reservoir , like a large tire. Then fill it for a minute or so and you have enough volume for a several second blow. I have a similar tire inflater , free standing, it is pretty hot after pumping a few minutes to top off four tires. So I doubt they are good to operate for hours.  It is about a $ 100 Michelin brand.

Comment: I see, so the reason for the absence of this adapter is that the compressors used for cars and bicycles are usually too weak to power a blow gun.